# Proper implementation of jQuery not

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a multi-tiered navigation of sorts and I'm not sure how to implement the .not function in this scenario.

If you take a look at the menu it works as intended, but I'd like to exlude the level 1 navigation so, when a child UL is opened the siblings of level 1 LIs are kept visible.

I'm not sure if I'm explaining this too well so've attached a jsfiddle in hopes someone can help me make this work.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ionko22/KEqS8/)

Here's my javascript (I know some vars are redundant and not optimized, it's for later use)

```
var navLevel1 = $(".level-1-list");
var navLevel2 = $(".level-2-list");
var navLevel3 = $(".level-3-list");
var navLevel4 = $(".level-4-list");
var navLevel5 = $(".level-5-list");

navLevel2.hide();
navLevel3.hide();
navLevel4.hide();
navLevel5.hide();


function listMenuTrigger(listItemWithChildren) {
 listItemWithChildren.next("ul").toggle();
  listItemWithChildren.closest("li").not("level-1-list li").siblings().toggle();//not not working

if (listItemWithChildren.next("ul").is(":visible")) {
    listItemWithChildren.removeClass("colapsed");   
    listItemWithChildren.addClass("expanded");  
}
else {
    listItemWithChildren.removeClass("expanded");   
    listItemWithChildren.addClass("colapsed");
}
}

$(".list-menu li:has(ul)").children("span").addClass("colapsed");

$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".colapsed").click(function(){       
   listMenuTrigger( $(this) );             
})
});
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: the .not part isn't working

Comment: What do you think it should do?

Comment: exclude the LIs if they are part of the ul with a class level-1-list. Is condescension part of the price for help on here these days?

Comment: I do not mean to condescend I just want to understand what you expect to happen when

Comment: If my answer was sufficient to solve your problem, I would certainly appreciate you marking it as correct. If it was not, please comment on it and I will do my best to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not referring to `level-1-list` as a class. (Also, you need to make sure you're only `not()`ing its direct children. That tripped me up for a moment.)

```
listItemWithChildren.closest("li").not(".level-1-list>li").siblings().toggle();//not now working
```

Edit to add: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KEqS8/6/)

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the 2nd pair of eyes!